# How to indicate data output from a subactivity in an Activity Diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, subactivity

as said in the title I am trying to indicate the output of data from a subactivity in an Activity Diagram. I am torn between Object-Nodes and input pins.

What is correct in this case?

Comment: Maybe useful: [Conrad Bock, UML 2 Activity and Action Models, Object Nodes](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2004_01/column3/)

Answer (score 1):

Input and output of `Activities` are routed through `ObjectNodes`. For the input you use an `ActivityParameter` which is a specialized `ObjectNode`. `ObjectNodes` are drawn as little squares at the border of `Activity`. `ActivityParameters` are shown as flat rectangular shapes also at the border of `Activities`.